# WPF Image Visibility Binding in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I’ve got a little problem binding an image to a Radiobuttion. I only want to bind it via XAML an what I did is this.. I createad a Stackpanel with 5 radiobutton in it..

```
    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <RadioButton GroupName="Group1" Content="1" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Width="35" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1"
                IsChecked="CodeBehindBinding..." />
        <RadioButton GroupName="Group1" Content="2" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="35" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1"
                IsChecked="{CodeBehindBinding..." />
    ......
```

Somewhere else in the XAML i tryied to bind a Label to the group. Together..

```
    <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Source="/*****;component/Resources/Checked.png" 
           Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, BindingGroupName=StackPanel1.Group1}"
           />
```

...Nothinig happens. ;-)  The Image is permanent visibile.

How can I fix it ? Hope you can help ..
Greetz Iki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things wrong here. First, you need to assign a `Name` to the RadioButton you want to use as binding source and use that for the binding's `ElementName` property.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton1" ... />
```

Then your binding also needs a converter from `bool` to `Visibility`. You could use WPF's [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter.aspx):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>radia

<Image Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=radioButton1,
                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ... />
```

Comment: Ah.. Ok I get it. But is there a possibility to bind the visibility to the group of radiobuttons ?

Comment: You would use a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx) with a [multi-value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) for that purpose.

Answer (score 7):

I assume that "IsChecked" property is Boolean.
In order to bind [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property you must bind to Visibility type property or use converter.

If you don't want to use converter you need to declare Visibility notification property:

```
    private Visibility isChecked= Visibility.Visible;
    public Visibility IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }
```

If you want to stay with your Boolean parameter, use 
[Visibility converter](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2008/10/27/binding-converters---visibilityconverter.aspx)