# Create WPF Function to Hidden Images Controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm currently developing a WPF C# Application that contains some textbox validations. If field is valid it must show a ok validation image if not valid it must show a wrong validation image, like an image below.
[image]

My Problem is how to set `visibility = visibility.Hidden` for all images if I click on cancelar button or another button. I know set `img1.visibility = visibility.Hidden;`, `img2.visibility = visibility.Hidden;`, `img3.visibility = visibility.Hidden;`... Works but i need to create a function to do it. I believe that I create a List of Images and pass this List of parameter to a function works fine and I can use this function for other validations. So how can I do it?

Comment: `Bind` the `Visibility` of each `Image` and Create the function to toggle between `Visible` and `Hidden`. Use `Converter` if you go with `bool` properties.

Comment: @AbinMathew How to do this?

Comment: [Find This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20189001/2470362)

Comment: Converter [Example](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/)

Comment: No problem hope it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this article : [Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms750612(v=vs.100).aspx)

If you implement data binding then you have just to bind properties:

```
<Image Source="..." Visibility="{Binding Img1Visibility}"/>
```

Implement ViewModel class via `INotifyPropertyChanged`

And then simply work with your Properties in code.

**UPD**

If you want to simply create function to work with your images then move your `img1.visibility = visibility.Hidden;`, `img2.visibility = visibility.Hidden;`, `img3.visibility = visibility.Hidden;` in separate function inside your MainWindow.xaml.cs file, you don't have to pass it as arguments as you work in one MainWindow class.

So simply:

```
private void Fun() 
{
    img1.visibility = visibility.Hidden;
    img2.visibility = visibility.Hidden;
    img3.visibility = visibility.Hidden;
}
```

And request your Fun() method from ClickButton handler.

Comment: @coreid Please mark answer as correct if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the image controls and iterate over it.

```
List<Image> _images = new List<Image>
{
    img1,
    img2,
    ...
};

void Cancelar()
{
    foreach (var image in _images)
    {
        image.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

But still, the code is awful. Witness me SO.

Comment: Let's do it better how?

Comment: @coreid Google for `WPF validation`.