# Wpf: Set Clr property in a Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have a `TextBox` and want to set a CLR property in ViewModel to another property in ViewModel when Visibility is changed.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Property1}">
<TextBox.Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
       <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
          <Trigger.Setters>
             ///Set Property1 = Property2
          </Trigger.Setters>
       </Trigger>
</Style>
</TextBox>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In wpf (+mvvm) it's typically done by binding `Visibility` property of view element to a `bool` property of viewmodel via `BoolToVisibility` converter ([click](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20189001/1997232)).

Answer (score 1):

Use an intermediary `DependencyProperty` and Right `BindingMode` Combination to achieve your desired Result :

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Property1}">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Visbility" Value="Collapsed">
                            <Trigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Property2}" />
                                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Mode=OneWayToSource,Path=property1}" />
                            </Trigger.Setters>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

I'm assuming that you want to set the value of property2(which is also a CLR property) in property1, which will ultimately set the `Text` Property of `TextBox`.

Comment: This will set Property1 to null initially because the `Tag` has null value so this solution will not work for me

Comment: @VivekSaurav so what i though you are trying to do it right? Also updated the style to set binding behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a way to do this. You bind the Visibility of the TextBox to a clr property of your VM and in the setter of the clr visibility property change the value of Property1

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Property1}" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=boolConvertor}}"></TextBox>
```

and in the VM

```
  public bool Visibility
    {
        get { return visibility; }
        set
        {
            visibility = value;
            if (visibility == false)
            {
                Property1 = Property2;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```